# How define a body parameter of a request is FormData or not

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I need to append a value (like an id) to all requests of a project, so I add it at the request interceptor. I do not want to lose all other parameters, with this line of code at interceptor:

```
request = request.clone({
    body: {...request.body, project: projectId}
});
```

if the parameters are of type `FormData` I face problem cause I should append the value to `FormData` but How can I make difference between `FormData` and simple object body.

Comment: It might be a lot easier to add that value as a get param to all requests. However, I can imagine you might be able to determine the encoding on the request. Of form-encoded you can append formData. To find out, just console the request and see if there are any keys on there you could use?

Comment: At least... `console.log(request.body instanceof FormData);` could give a hint.

Comment: Thanks @AT82 yes I think using `instanceof` will solve the issue